# UIViewController does not release its views

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I was trying to fix a memory leak in my application and stumbled upon a very interesting thing. Now i'm not sure if there's a bug that i made somewhere or simply misuse of the technology so i'll try to get things clear with your help. Here's what happens:

- i create a custom uiviewcontroller that loads its view from nib file
- i release the controller
- controller's dealloc method gets called where i release a custom view that i've specifically added to the view hierarchy as an outlet (i made a retainable property out of it). It has a dealloc method with a call to nslog.
- the main view in the nib file (connected to controller's view outlet) is also a subclass of a uiview which also has a call to nslog in its dealloc

The problem is - even though the uiviewcontroller's dealloc is getting called, neither the main view nor the child (the one with outlet) gets released (their NSLogs don't fire).

Is it normal that this happens? Maybe iOS doesn't release the views right away? Or should i start looking for bugs in the code? If so - what could be the most probable causes?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Do you have your main view attached in IB to a retaining property of your view controller that you're not releasing? Maybe?

Comment: I think you need to post some code as it's hard to understand exactly what you have done. But it definitely sounds like you are leaking objects.

Comment: See my own answer below. It was my own bug obviously.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with late night debugging is that you don't consider even the simplest angles. Since i like to know how things work and do everything from scratch, i've created my own system for switching view controllers. The problem was that even though i used to deallocate the view controller when needed, i forgot to remove it from superview, thus having one more retain too many. Now there's a leak somewhere else, but i'm sure i'll solve it myself. Thanks for your comments.